# React conditional rendering is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

```
function SearchForm(props) {
    return(
            <div id="input">
                <form>
                    <input
                        id="search-keyword"
                        type='text'
                        onKeyDown={props.onKeyDown}
                        defaultValue={props.keyword}
                        />
                </form>
            </div>
          
    )
}

class MainPlate extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loginStatus : false,
            languageStatus : 0, //default English
            location: '',
            keyword: false
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
        if(this.state.keyword){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    searchByKeyword(e){
        const keyName = e.key;
        const inputKeyword = e.target.value;
            if(keyName === 'Enter'){

                console.log('typed keyword is',inputKeyword);

                this.setState({
                    keyword : inputKeyword
                })
                
            }
    }
    

    render(){

        if(!this.state.keyword){
            return(
                <div>
                    <header id='menu-bar'>
                    </header>
                    <main>
                        <img id='main-logo' src={mainLogo}/>
                        <SearchForm
                        onKeyDown={(e) => this.searchByKeyword(e)}/>
                    </main>
                    
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{

            return(
                <div>
                    <header id='menu-bar'>
                        <img id='bar-logo' src={barLogo}/>
                        <SearchForm
                        onKeyDown={(e) => this.searchByKeyword(e)}
                        keyword={this.state.keyword}/>
                    </header>
                    <main>
                        <div id='productGroup' >
                        </div>
                    </main>
                </div>
                
            );
        }
        
    }

}
```

First image - no keyword typed
[image: When react start from this]
Secont image - “react” typed as keyword and keyword state is set as react
[image: This goes as i thought]
Third image - type some text in input element and press enter then rerender as this image with be reset state
[image: Not goes as i thought]

After “keyword” of state is assigned, then else statement in render of MainPlate should be rerendered when I press enter key with some text in input element. But It render third image when press enter in second image of html(I think react rerender second image with changed keyword) when type text and press enter also reset component state value. Thanks for any advice. I can't figure it out what makes problem.

(Firstable I referenced old document which is not managed. So I think above code might not compatible with present version of react. But when I test example of document It works fine)